# Prove $k_n \leq k_{n+1}\leq t_{n+1}\leq t_n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0 < k_1 < t_1$  and for every integer $n \geq 1$, set $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$ and $t_{n+1} =(k_n+t_n)/2$. Prove that for every integer $n \geq 1$ we have $k_n \leq k_{n+1}\leq t_{n+1}\leq t_n$.

This is what I was thinking...

Let $0 < k_1 < t_1$  and $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$,  $t_{n+1} =(k_n+t_n)/2$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ be given. Using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, then $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n} \leq (k_n+t_n)/2 = t_{n+1}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $0  < k_1  \leq t_1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $t_{n+1} =(k_n+t_n)/2$ then $t_{n+1} =(k_n+t_n)/2 \leq (t_n+t_n)/2 = t_n$. Similarly, since $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$ then $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n} \geq \sqrt{k_nk_n} = \sqrt{k_n^2}= k_n$. Therefore, $K_n \leq t_n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and hence $k_n \leq k_{n+1}\leq t_{n+1}\leq t_n$.

Is this how you would correctly prove this?

Comment: Your proof completly correct! Congratulations

Comment: Is it possible to prove this without using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality?